# ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApi Support For Multiple HttpConfigurations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In WepApi 6 we were making use of multiple configuration options by passing the config on the route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<UserService>("1.0/User/", defaultWebApiConfiguration);
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<SomeOtherService>("1.0/SomeOtherService/", largeFilesConfig);
```

Where things like "MaxBufferSize", "MaxReceivedMessageSize", and "TransferMode" were set set appropriately. How can I acheive the same effect using an ASP.NET hosted application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't at the moment.  You can create multiple hosts in self-host but in MVC hosted there currently is just one config.